# form templating in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Is there as other way other than to call form as

```
{{form}}
```

because i need to place the text in different places in the html class

model.py

```
class Venue(models.Model):
venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
rent = models.IntegerField()
parking_area = models.IntegerField()
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to print the picture as well in html page like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do it manually, if necessary. Examples are available in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).